# Sharing files without letting the end users store them into their PC

Tags: file, share

We got PDF files that are only allowed to be viewed in the office. Some users keep those files in the flash drive disk and bring them home or send them to their email. What'd be the best way to prevent this situation. Taking a screenshot of screen is still enabled.

> Network : 100 Mbps LAN-based
>   Number of concurrent users to view file
>   : Around 50 at a time.

Comment: Not possible, unless you use/write a program to display pdfs without providing access to the files themselves

Comment: Fire people who violate security rules.

Comment: How about uploading PDF files in shared folder and make them open the files only in web browser?

Answer (score 0):

If a user can read a file, he can copy it.  You definitely need a piece of software to act as the go-between.  There are a few software solutions out there that use DRM encryption to protect your PDF files.  Some claim to prevent screen captures as well.

In your situation, you would probably want to have the DRM software check for a license certificate server on your network to ensure they are at the office before letting them open the file.  This would allow them to still use take-home thumbdrives and laptops to get work done.

Try searching for "PDF DRM" and see what you find.